# Raspberry Pi Pico W Sim800l

Tags: pi-pico-w

I want to send a "Hello World" message to the number I want using Raspberry Pi Pico W and Sim800l via sms.  How can I do that?
(Micropython)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly learn how to write a program with MicroPython on the Pico.

Secondly read and understand the documentation for the Sim8001 device.

Thirdly code and test a program to send "Hello World" to the number using SMS.

Good luck.